# How to bypass external hard drive permissions

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I bought an external hard drive from a computer repairman when he could not fix the computer I brought in for repair. I have not been able to access it since bringing it home to use because access is denied to me and I do not have permission to access the files. I did not do this and he wants to charge me to undo what he did. How can I remove these permissions myself  or is this money wasted? Computer needing repair was an ace notebook eMachines

Comment: You need to find a different repairer if he's trying to charge you  for the privilege of accessing *your own* files that were previously accessible to you, but now aren't as a result of his work. You have reasonable grounds to take legal action against him as this is tantamount to blackmail.

Comment: Is this a disk that you expect to contain your files, or do you expect it to be blank? Are you running as administrator? Have you tried to take ownership?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an account with admin privileged?  You should be able to access the security settings of the external drive and get access.

There are tons of instructions available via Google.  This [Link](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2159003/external-hard-drive-access-denied.html) can get you started.